# Ole 800A03EC error when using TExcelWorkBook SaveAs method in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, excel, automation, ole

I am trying to open excel 2003 workbook and save it as something else, for example excel 95.
I use the following code:

```
XLSApp:=TExcelApplication.Create(Self);
XLSApp.Workbooks.Open(SomeFileName,NULL,false,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,defaultlcid);
XLSWB:=TExcelWorkbook.Create(XLSApp);
XLSWB.ConnectTo(XLSApp.Workbooks.Item[1]);
XLSWB.SaveCopyAs(ExtractFilePath(edTable.Text)+'temp.xls');
XLSWB.SaveAs(SomeOtherFileName,xlExcel7,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,False,False,xlNoChange,xlUserResolution,False,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,DefaultLCID);
```

Unfortunately this code gives "Ole 800A03EC" on clients computer, while it works on mine. Note that I have Office 2007 installed, and he has Office 2003 SP3.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen this error once when automating Excel. It happened when the user had a cell in editmode and you tried to automate that instance. Excel doesn't like it when you are editing a cell and some program is fiddling around in the background.

So this is what's happening at your client (I think):

- Your client has Excel open and is
  editing a cell (select a cell and
  press F2)
- Your code starts:

  - You create a TExcelApplication and accesses the Workbooks property. Since your Excel application is not yet connected it calls TOleServer.Connect (look at the implementation of GetDefaultInterface)
  - Since the default connectkind is ckRunningOrNew, TExcelApplication connects to the running instance.
  - Because the client is editing a cell you get an error on the Open method.

How you can prevent this: Set ConnectKind of your TExcelApplication to ckNewInstance so you'll always work in a separate Excel instance.

Answer (score 3):

800A03EC also occurs when one (like, me) does a dumb thing like trying to load into an Excel cell that doesn't exist, like:

```
excel.Cells[rowIndex, ri] = x;
where ri is 0.
```

NOTE BENE: The `col` index starts at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

In my case ( xlExcel8 format ):

Instead of:

```
theWorkbookWyjscie.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, myExcel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
```

I used:

```
theWorkbookWyjscie.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

or

```
theWorkbookWyjscie.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, myExcel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel7);
```

Both work well... And yes, I know this is a stupid solution, but it's working!

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting that error when trying to store too much data to the WorkSheet (through Delphi)

Answer (score 1):

OLE 800A03EC usually has to do with invalid characters in your Excel file. Are you using the same data as your client? Is there a difference in Regional Settings? Etc. etc. there could be number of errors for this, but most likely (as a quick google told me) it is a regional setting.

Comment: The regional settings are probably different. The file we use is the same. I need the program to run smoothly on any reginal settings though, so what should I do?